# How to solve "Missing delimiter (. inserted) \end{eqnarray*}"?

Tags: math-mode, errors, delimiters

How can I solve this problem?

[image]

I have so many similar to this problem.

Comment: isn't this identical to the question you just asked? You need `\right.` (your image shows no `.` after `\right`) but please do not show an image of your source code, post the actual text.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376115/miktex-tex-studio-missing-delimiter-inserted

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add `.` after `\right` even if there is nothing to show in the typeset. This informs TeX engine that the brackets now ended. Check this code for example:

```
\begin{equation}
P_{e, \thinspace WT} =
\left \{
%
    \begin{aligned}
        %
        & 0  &   & v_{w} \thinspace < \thinspace v_{ci} 
        \\
        & P_{GCR} (v_{w}) \quad   & v_{ci} \thinspace \leq \thinspace &  v_{w} \thinspace \leq v_{r} 
        \\
        & P_{r, \thinspace WT}   & v_{r} \thinspace \leq \thinspace  &  v_{w} \thinspace \leq v_{co}
        \\
        & 0  &   & v_{w} > \thinspace v_{co}
        %
    \end{aligned}
%
\right
%
\label{eq:WTPSC}
\end{equation}
```

Without the dot after `\right`, you will get a similar error to that shown above. Use the following code (the same as above but with `\right.`):

```
\begin{equation}
P_{e, \thinspace WT} =
\left \{
%
    \begin{aligned}
        %
        & 0  &   & v_{w} \thinspace < \thinspace v_{ci} 
        \\
        & P_{GCR} (v_{w}) \quad   & v_{ci} \thinspace \leq \thinspace &  v_{w} \thinspace \leq v_{r} 
        \\
        & P_{r, \thinspace WT}   & v_{r} \thinspace \leq \thinspace  &  v_{w} \thinspace \leq v_{co}
        \\
        & 0  &   & v_{w} > \thinspace v_{co}
        %
    \end{aligned}
%
\right.
%
\label{eq:WTPSC}
\end{equation}
```

You will get:

[image]

Which means after finishing all of the cases close the set of equations, but not with another curly bracket - simply close it with the "nothing" bracket!

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem.